# Не удается запустить PHPDaemon  - PECL eio event

Tags: php, pecl, centos

Здравствуйте, господа. )

Хочу поднять PHPDaemon на Centos 6, все вроде бы сделал, но не тут то было... Не удается запустить PHPDaemon, ругается на - PECL eio event. Версии eio и event свежие, пару дней ищу решение проблемы, но что-то ничего нет подходящего.

```
# sudo phpd start --verbose-tty=1
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/event.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/event.so: undefined symbol: php_sockets_le_socket in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php/modules/eio.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/eio.so: undefined symbol: php_sockets_le_socket in Unknown on line 0
[PHPD] FS: missing pecl-eio >= 1.2.1. Filesystem I/O performance compromised. Consider installing pecl-eio. `pecl install http://pecl.php.net/get/eio-1.2.1.tgz`
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/ExampleJabberBot.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/FastCGI.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/FlashpolicyServer.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/HTTPServer.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/IdentServer.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/SSL-sample.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: 'conf/conf.d/WebSocketServer.conf'
[PHPD] Loaded config file: '/usr/local/phpdaemon/conf/phpd.conf'
[PHPD] [EMERG] event extension >= 1.6.1 not found (or OUTDATED). You have to install it. `pecl install http://pecl.php.net/get/event-1.6.1.tgz`
```

Прошу слёзно)))) Подскажите, ребята, как вылечить сие дело. )) Заранее благодарствую. )

**Обновление**

До того как начал установку, обновил PHP с 5.3 до 5.6, что-то у меня подозрения на некорректное обновление, так как сервер на данный момент не используется, позволил себе полностью все снести и установить все что нужно, свежее на чистую, без всякий обновлений старых версий, надеюсь, проблема решится.

В Сети много различных инструкций по установке PHPDaemon, но как-то каждый по-своему все пишет, поделитесь ссылкой на проверенные инструкции установки, если несложно.

Comment: @АлексейII, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: предположу, что нужен libevent

Comment: @АлексейII, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Добрый день, обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так решил проблему:

1)

```
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/event-2.1.0.tgz
tar zxvf event-2.1.0.tgz
phpize && ./configure -with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config
make && make install
```

2) add "extension=event.so" to php.ini 
3)

```
/usr/bin/env php -m|grep event
и
php -v

Получил: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/pecl.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/pecl.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
event
4) Открыл /etc/php5/mods-available/pecl.ini для редактирования
а) закомментировал строку с вызовом модуля: 
;extension=pecl.so 
б) затем после этой строки добавил 2-е строки с вызовом модулей:
extension=raphf.so
extension=http.so
в) в /etc/php5/mods-available/raphf.ini закоментировал вызов модуля: ;extension=raphf.so. 
Это нужно для того, чтобы модуль raphf.so вызывался раньше http.so, если не вызывать до http.so то будет другая ошибка появляться: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so' - /usr/lib/php5/20131226/http.so: undefined symbol: php_persistent_handle_abandon in Unknown on line 0)
```

Comment: Забыл уточнить, что нулевым пунктом (т.е. перед пунктом №1) выполнил команду:

Comment: "pecl uninstall event". В принципе после можно воспользоваться попробовать другой способ установки - командой "pecl install event eio" - скорее всего установка пройдёт удачно (сам не пробовал)